# FBDialog scrollViewDidScroll unrecognized selector

Tags: facebook, ios5, sdk, ios6

I'm following this simple [HOW TO](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/feed-dialog-using-ios-sdk/) to get Facebook working with both iOS5 and iOS6.

This is working great with iOS6 but I get the following error with iOS5.

The dialog is appearing but since I try to touch the screen the app is crashing.

This is the code:

```
// Invoke the dialog
[mainDelegate.facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

This is the error:

```
-[FBDialog scrollViewDidScroll:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x40b4550
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@implementation UIWebView(CustomScroll)
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    [self.delegate scrollViewDidScroll: scrollView];
}
@end
```

The problem was caused by this code in a class I was importing.